# Why SSRS colour from expression is not working?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to have a dynamic color for some objects in my report (font color, background fill of text box etc.). I was trying to get it from either Parameter or Variable, but nothing worked, the color evaluates to White.
I used these for example:
`=Variables!Hdr1_Color.Value`
`=Parameters!Hdr1_Color.Value`
I even tried this: `="Green"`
but none of these commands work, color stays White.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ACe.png)

Report Builder 15.0.19611.0
SQL Server 2019 Reporting Services
Version 15.0.7961.31630

Has anyone seen/solved something like that?

Comment: What Properties are you setting this expression on? `="Green"` should definitely set a colour so the only thing I can think of is the wrong colour Property is being set.

Comment: I tried multiple functions, color names, hex values but to no avail. The only way to change the color is to enter the hardcoded value (without equal sign and quotes)

Comment: Okay, but what actual Property are you setting?

Comment: For example TextBox-Fill-BackgroundColor or TextBox-Font-Color